# Insertion function won't return any nodes

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to build a BST insertion function, but it won't return any nodes that I inserted in the main function.

Here is my program:

```
// BST structure
typedef struct bin_tree{
   int data;
   struct bin_tree *left;
   struct bin_tree *right;
}bin_t;

// create a new tree  
bin_t *newTree(int val){
   bin_t *nnode = (bin_t *)malloc(sizeof(bin_t));
   nnode->data = val;
   nnode->left = NULL;
   nnode->right = NULL;
   return nnode;
}

// insertion function
void insert(bin_t *tree, int val){
   if(tree == NULL){
      tree = newTree(val);
   }else{ 
      if(val < (tree->data)){
          insert(tree->left, val);
      }else if(val > (tree->data)){
          insert(tree->right, val);
      }
   }
}

void print_inorder(bin_t *tree)
{
   if (tree)
   {
       print_inorder(tree->left);
       printf("%d\n",tree->data);
       print_inorder(tree->right);
   }
}


int main(){
   bin_t *root = NULL;
   insert(root, 6);
   insert(root, 45);
   insert(root, 66);
   insert(root, 3);
   insert(root, 9);
   insert(root, 33);
   insert(root, 34);
   printf("In Order Display: \n");
   print_inorder(root);
}
```

And it works if I make the tree argument to pointer to pointer in the insert function:

```
void insert(bin_tree **tree, int val)
```

Or return the address of the new node(tree) in the insert function.

My problem is, is there another way to insert a node and that it will return the address/value from the insert function, and then I can print it in order? Since this insertion function is the hw requirement and I can't change it. Also does it matter if I place the root node on the global(tried, but still not working, and don't know why)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For one thing, your `insert` function should return the new root of the tree.  If  `tree` is `NULL`, it performs a local assignment to `tree`, then discards the value and simply returns.  This is no different than doing nothing and returning (and in fact, your compiler probably deletes the assignment as "dead code").

Comment: The comment and the functionality of your `newTree()` function don't match.  There's no question of emptiness in the function shown.

Comment: Tom's comment is spot on.  This is also a duplicate of goodness only knows how many other questions with the same basic problem.  I've chosen one reasonable duplicate, but I very much doubt it is the 'canonical' one that should be used.

Comment: I personally prefer the passing the pointer to the root pointer method. though a wrapper struct that holds the root pointer might be more elegant.

Comment: But won't' void insert() will return the value of the tree after it executes? (Maybe I am wrong)

Comment: No, of course not.  It's *void*.  That means it doesn't return anything.  And even if it isn't void, you have to explicitly *return* something.  Remember, C is call by value, not call by reference.